# Understanding ternary representation of Cantor set

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

What is $a_1$ , $a_2$? How is this construction done ?

Link for file = [https://sites.math.washington.edu/~hart/m424/Cantorset.pdf](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Ehart/m424/Cantorset.pdf)

Comment: From the picture: "$a_1$ is the largest integer such that $a_1/3\le x$".

Comment: yes what is this mean ?

Comment: Multiply $x$ by $3$, then round the result down to the nearest whole number.

Comment: See this, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415018/ternary-representation-of-cantor-set

Comment: You can think $ a_{1} $ as the box function $[3x] $, where $[3x] $ means greatest integer less than or equal to $ 3x $.

Comment: @Subhajit but what is use of this ?

Comment: It's the definition of $ a_{1} $, what you have given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The formula:**

Given a number $x$, Let's start by defining $x_1 \equiv x$. Then $a_1 \equiv \lfloor 3x_1 \rfloor$ where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is the ['greatest integer function'/'floor function](https://brilliant.org/wiki/floor-function/). Now take the part that is "left over": Let $x_2 = x_1 - a_1/3$. Then build $a_2 \equiv \lfloor 3^2 x_2 \rfloor$. Now set $x_3 = x_2 - a_3/3^2$. Keep going. In general:

$$
\begin{matrix}
& x_1 =  & x & \mid & a_1 =  & \lfloor 3x_1 \rfloor \\
& x_2 =  & x_1 - a_1/3 & \mid & a_2 =  &\lfloor 3^2 x_2 \rfloor \\
& x_3 =  & x_2 - a_2/3^2 & \mid & a_3 =  & \lfloor 3^3 x_3 \rfloor \\
& x_4 =  & x_3 - a_3/3^4 & \mid & a_4 =  & \lfloor 3^4 x_4 \rfloor \\
& \vdots & \vdots      & \vdots        & \vdots   \\
& x_i =  & x_{i-1} - a_{i-1}/3^i & \mid & a_i =  & \lfloor 3^i x_i \rfloor \\
\end{matrix}
$$

**What this is  *trying to do*:**

Let's stick to base 10, since that's what we're intuitively used to. So in the above formulae for $x_i$ and $a_i$, replace $3$ with $10$. Now pick some number $x \in [0, 1)$. For example, let's pick $x = 0.1984$. We want the $a_i$ to be giving us the "digits" of $x$ after the decimal point. So we want $a_1 = 1, a_2 = 9, a_3 = 8, a_4 = 4$. If the digit thing doesn't make sense, here's a rough picture:

```
0. 1  9   8  4
   a1 a2  a3 a4
```

Let's calculate using the formula and check:

- $x_1 = x = 0.1984$
- $a_1 = \lfloor 10 x_1 \rfloor = \lfloor 10 \times 0.1984 \rfloor = \lfloor  1.984 \rfloor = 1$. So we peeled off the first digit of the decimal expansion ($1$) of $0.1894$ as $a_1$.
- $x_2 = x_1 - a_1/10 = 0.1984 - 1/10 = 0.1984 - 0.1 = 0.0984$
- $a_2 = \lfloor 10^2 x_2 \rfloor = \lfloor 10^2 \times 0.0984 \rfloor = \lfloor 9.84 \rfloor = 9$. Great, so $a_2$ is the second digit after the dot in the decimal expansion of $x$.
- $x_3 = x_2 - a_2/10^2 = 0.0984 - 9/100 = 0.0984 - 0.09 = 0.0084$.
- $a_3 = \lfloor 10^3 x_3 \rfloor = \lfloor 10^3 \times 0.0084 \rfloor = \lfloor 8.4 \rfloor = 8$.
- $x_4 = x_3 - a_3/10^3 = 0.0084 - 8/1000 = 0.0084 - 0.008 = 0.0004$
- $a_4 = \lfloor 10^4 x_4 \rfloor = \lfloor 1000 \times 0.0004 \rfloor = \lfloor 4 \rfloor = 4$.
- $x_5 = x_4 - a_4/10^4 = 0.0004 - 4/10000 = 0.0004 - 0.0004 = 0$.
- Now we stop, because all further $x_i$ and $a_i$ will be $0$.

But we can imagine a number like $y = 0.12112111211112111112\dots$ which keeps repeating forever. This will have an infinite sequence of $x_i$ and $a_i$. The above equations are trying to compute this infinite sequence of $a_i$.

The *exact same story* works out in the base 3 case. I chose base $10$ since we're most familiar with it; It maybe enlightening to try to do this in base 3 by had.

**The big picture/How this relates to the cantor set**

- Think of how we build the cantor set: we divide the line into three parts, throw away the middle section, and continue dividing the left and right segments:

[image]

- So when we see a number in ternary, it can be $0.0\dots$, $0.1\dots$, $0.2\dots$. The part that has $0.1\dots$ will be in the "middle portion", since it's value is between $[1/3, 2/3)$ (think in analogy to decimal: a number that is $0.1\dots$ has value between $[1/10, 2/10)$).
- But these numbers with values between $[1/3, 2/3)$ are precisely the numbers we want to "throw away" when building the cantor set.
- So we build these $a_i$s to learn what digits the number has. Then we decide if it stays or not based on whether *all* digits are either $0$ or $2$. Written formally, this becomes: $\forall i \in \mathbb N, a_i = 0 \lor a_i = 2$.
- This then allows us to prove things about the cantor set, since we have gone from a "geometric" definition (remove middle one third of a line), to an algebraic/digit based definition (those numbers whose ternary expansion is 0 or 2).

Comment: Thank you. That is what i was looking for. Can you mention some references ?

Comment: In second (and furthure) iteration two mid intervals are thrown off and so on. So doesnot some numbers who has 0 or 1 gets thrown off too ?

Comment: what i mean is that parts of  interval [0, 1/3 ) is thrown off too. so doesnot it removes some numbers from set having o and 2's